Low voltage trigger switch
I have a circuit that does not work.
I am using a BT151 to use as a switch. It will be activated when a tilt switch is tilted (for a van alarm.) The thing is, when the switch is tilted it just makes a quick touch on the connectors so the alarm does not stay on.
My thought was as soon as its triggered it uses the BT151 to keep a voltage on the alarm even if the tilt switch goes to off.
The operating voltage is 12V. I have a board that switches a voice message then switches on a siren alarm but it needs a constant voltage.
Any ideas and circuits?
Just to recap:  I need a latching switch that keeps a voltage of 12V on even after the switch has been switched off, like if a laser had been triggered.

Bistable relay?

Something like the MAX16150A (or family parts) could be good for this application, as mentioned the BT151 isn't great for this application.

Thanks I ordered a flip flop bistable unit from Ebay hope that will do the trick, as explained I googled for something to do the job and most pointed to to the thyristor BUT what was not told to me is it had to be a constant supply which was not the brief, hope this does the job. Electronic Switch Latch Bistable Self-locking Trigger Board for LED Motor Household Appliance 6A DC 3V 3.3V 3.7V 5V

The BT151 is a thyristor, and thyristors require a certain minimum current through them to remain on. In the case of the BT151, that current can be as high as 20 mA:

I wouldn't be surprised if your alarm doesn't draw that much current. If that's the case, the thyristor won't stay on when the gate signal is removed.
A thyristor probably isn't the best choice for this application, anyway. There are other methods to latch a signal on that will have less voltage drop (see the "on-state voltage" spec just below the holding current in the image above), which may also be an issue in your application; will your 12 V alarm still operate at 10.25 V? (more realistically, at 11 V, as the drop does go down at lower currents)

Wondered why it switched off lol I did google and it came with a circuit but as you say when the switch / trigger was removed it goes off. What would you recommend ?

I can see some on amazon Bistable flip flop BUT the reviews say thy are not true latching as when trigger power is removed thy reset ? I need the power to stay on when trigger load is removed (well until the load switched on to the alarm is re set)

You might try adding a resistor (e.g. about 500Ω) from +12V to the thyristor anode to provide at least 20mA of current when triggered.
